# Insert/Remove item in listbox bound to database

Tags: sql, wpf, sorting, binding

I want to be able to reorder my listbox which is bound to my sql ce database by clicking up and down arrow buttons. Since my listbox is populated directly from my database using the entity framework, I think I have to delete the object (from the listbox) and reinsert it (in the row above) if I want to move the item up the list.

I have no view model, my listbox is populated directly from my database in my code like this:

```
listBoxProperties.ItemsSource = entities.Properties.ToList();
```

Does my question make sense?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ormally you would handle the moving of your list item in your view model which would hold the ObservableCollection the control was bound to - and then that would be reflected in your control via the binding.
It is going to get messy trying to accomplish this dirrectly on the control - which is your only way since your binding to a throwaway copy of the EF properties list.
As your UI dev goes on you are only going to run into more issues like this.  I strongly recommend getting a view model in place sooner rather that later.

Comment: How much work would be involved in adding a view model? Would it simply involve adding the new class for the entity and then simply changing my datacontext to that of the view model? What about my code behind?

Comment: Ive done apps with out view model and it has proved a lot of work down the track as the app grew in complexity + in the end I had to rewrite to view model to make it work.  Your view model is just a light wrapper/adapter that adapts your model element to better fit bindings.  Eg your model (EF) List would become an ObservableCollection and the view list box would bind to that.  Then you just do a reorder on the ObservableCollection and the view updates.